# Cannot match rvalue reference function with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, overloading, rvalue-reference

When attempting to use an rvalue reference, I get an error from GCC (clang does not generate an error).

**Why is the compiler generating an error? Is it a bug in GCC?**

The "simplified" error is:

> `|In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/sstream:38,`
>   `|                 from .code.tio.cpp:1:`
>   `|/usr/include/c++/8/istream: In instantiation of 'struct std::__is_extractable<std::istream&, std::istream& (*&)(std::istream&, std::string&), void>':`
>   `|/usr/include/c++/8/type_traits:131:12:   required from 'struct std::__and_<std::__is_convertible_to_basic_istream<std::istringstream > >, std::__is_extractable<std::istream&, std::istream& (*&)(std::istream&, std::string&), void> >'`
>   `|/usr/include/c++/8/type_traits:136:12:   required from 'struct std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_lvalue_reference<std::istringstream > > >, std::__is_convertible_to_basic_istream<std::istringstream > >, std::__is_extractable<std::istream&, std::istream& (*&)(std::istream&, std::string&), void> >'`
>   `|/usr/include/c++/8/istream:980:5:   required by substitution of 'template<class _Istream, class _Tp> typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp> >, std::__is_convertible_to_basic_istream<_Istream>, std::__is_extractable<typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_istream<_Tp>::__istream_type, _Tp&&, void> >::value, typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_istream<_Tp>::__istream_type>::type std::operator>>(_Istream&&, _Tp&&) [with _Istream = std::istringstream; _Tp = std::istream& (*&)(std::istream&, std::string&)]'`
>   `|.code.tio.cpp:12:32:   required from here`
>   `|/usr/include/c++/8/istream:951:12: error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream' and 'std::istream& (*)(std::istream&, std::string&)')`
>   `|             __void_t<decltype(declval<_Istream&>()`
>   `|                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`
>   `|                 >> declval<_Tp>())>>`
>   `|                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

The code I am trying to compile is:

```
typedef std::istream &getline_type(std::istream &, std::string &);

void operator>>(std::istream &, getline_type) {}   // 1
void operator>>(std::istream &&, getline_type) {}

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    getline_type *getline = std::getline;          // 2
    //using std::getline;                          // 3
    std::istringstream("a") >> getline;
}
```

If I comment out the line marked `// 1`, it works. If I use the line marked `// 3` instead of `// 2`, it also works.

I believe clang is correctly assessing that the code is well-formed, but if there is a valid reason to reject the code, it might indicate a bug in clang.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5NCoMwEIX3OcVgQUxpca9trlJCMpUBjcFEoYhnT60RsVjo7N7PNzxl7bVSKpzIqLrXCDfnfIeyEcG/LGp8gvO6KCi6kFboazL4@KTZd3SJ1VmSqSDlJWNDSxpai530bSfEAdh/4zBOf4BfBCPjoZFkMs5GBvPtV7hysfYUnFcF91hdZWzmee8W8JBsU@Y4DsoSmXAQArbeFMIb)

Comment: Appears to be ADL-related. Slapping the overloads inside `using namespace std { /* declarations go here */ }` makes gcc happy. gcc must be finding a declaration for a `>>` overload via ADL in the `std` namespace, doesn't find a suitable overload, and gives up.

Comment: You should include the chain-of-instantiation information n your question (not just via the link).

Comment: I thought at first you might have a pretty good entry for the Code Golf contest [Generate the longest error message in C++](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1956/generate-the-longest-error-message-in-c), but after I looked at some of the other entries, you are sadly not even in the running.

Comment: @DavisHerring: Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does appear to be a GCC bug: the [line](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-8/libstdc++-v3/include/std/istream#L951) at which the overload resolution fails is part of the declaration of a **partial specialization** for a trait, so a substitution failure should just have the usual effect of eliminating the “overload” (the partial specialization) and thus producing `false_type` for the trait.  Then the `operator>>` template specialization would itself be eliminated for the same reason, leaving your overloads.  I assume that GCC is letting your functions **bleed** into the lookup set (but only partially, since it then rejects for want of an `istream&` overload after all).

Comment: You are saying SFINAE should have kicked in and make the compiler try a different overload?

Comment: @jxh: Yes, that should have happened twice—once among partial specializations of the `__is_extractable` trait, and then among the overloads of `operator>>` (but it never got to that second step).